# Is this “limit” of a sequence of $L^2$ functions in $L^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Suppose we have a sequence $\{f_n\}$ in $L^2([0,1])$ and a Lebesgue measurable $f$ such that $$\int_E f_ndx\rightarrow\int_E fdx$$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ for every Lebesgue measurable subset $E\subseteq[0,1]$. If $\sup_n\|f_n\|_2<\infty$, then do we necessarily have $f\in L^2([0,1])$?

I’m not seeing how to show this, one way or the other. I tried constructing a counterexample along the lines of $f_n(x)=x^{\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2}}$, since then $f(x)=x^{-1/2}$ isn’t square-integrable, but this doesn’t satisfy either condition. I’m inclined to think that we do have $f\in L^2([0,1])$, since it doesn’t seem like you can make $\int_{[0,1]}|f|^2dx$ blow up without either of $\int_{[0,1]}|f_n|^2dx$ or $\int f dx$ blowing up, but I don’t see a way to formalize or justify this instinct.

Comment: Have you heard of weak convergence?

Comment: @DanielFischer I’ve heard of it, but I am not proficient with the idea.

Comment: That's a pity, because I can't think of another nice way to prove $f \in L^2([0,1])$. How unfamiliar are you with functional analysis?

Comment: @DanielFischer I am unfamiliar enough that I didn’t realize that this was a question that might even remotely require functional analysis.

Comment: I don't think it requires functional analysis, it just goes nicer if you can employ heavy machinery. But maybe it's less fiddling to do it without than I thought. Unfortunately it's too hot to think properly, so I'm rather slow right now.

Comment: This looks like something that relies on Radon-Nikodym Theorem, convergence of measures and representation theorems. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem

Comment: If $\{f_n\}$ is a bounded sequence, then it has a weakly convergent subsequence $f_{n_k}$ to some $g \in L^2$. This means that $\int_0^1 f_{n_k}h \to \int_0^1 g h$ for all $h \in L^2([0, 1])$. Then you just need to show $g = f$. This should follow by letting $h = \chi_{E}$ for an arbitrary $E \subset [0, 1]$ measurable.

Comment: It isn't actually so bad doing it without weak convergence. However, if you understand what Chris has outlined, that way is still nicer and shorter than the lower-tech way.

Comment: @DanielFischer While I can kind of see how Chris’s argument works, I’d still be interested in knowing how this might work without weak convergence.

Comment: Step 1, separate real and imaginary parts. We have the same relation for $\operatorname{Re} f_n$ and $\operatorname{Re} f$, and $\lVert \operatorname{Re} f_n\rVert_2 \leqslant \lVert f_n\rVert_2$. Step 2, by linearity of integrals we have $\int f_n\cdot s\,dx \to \int f\cdot s\,dx$ for every simple measurable $s$. Step 3, take a sequence $(s_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ of non-negative simple functions such that $s_k \leqslant s_{k+1}$ and $s_k(x) \to f^+(x)$ almost everywhere, where $f^+$ is the positive part of $f$. Step 4, for every $k$ we have

Comment: $$\lVert s_k\rVert_2^2 \leqslant \int f\cdot s_k\,dx = \lim_{n \to \infty} \int f_n\cdot s_k\,dx \leqslant C\cdot \lVert s_k\rVert_2$$ using Cauchy-Schwarz. Therefore $\lVert s_k\rVert_2 \leqslant C$, and it follows that $f^+ \in L^2$ with $\lVert f^+\rVert_2 \leqslant C$. Step 5, the same for the negative part of $f$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I prefer the "functional analysis" approach, as it is more natural to me; but here is a pure measure-theory argument. All it uses is the definition of Lebesgue integral and the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.*

The key observation is that, by linearity, the property can be written as
$$
\int_F f\,s=\lim_n\int_F f_n\,s
$$
for any measurable set $F$ and any simple function $s$.

I will assume $f$ real; if it is complex, one can work with real and imaginary parts, so no loss of generality.

Suppose that $f\not\in L^2[0,1]$. That is, $$\int_{[0,1]}f^2=\infty.$$
By working on the set $F=\{f\geq0\}$, we may assume $\int_F f^2=\infty$ (otherwise, we work with $-f$). By definition of Lebesgue integral, this means that there exists a sequence of simple functions $\{s_m\}$ with $0\leq s_m\leq f^2$ and $\lim_m\int_F s_m=\infty$. By choosing a subsequence if necessary, we may assume that the numbers $\int_Fs_m$ increase monotonically.

Choose positive integers $k(m)$ with $k(m)\leq \int_Fs_m< k(m)+1$. Then $k(m)\nearrow\infty$. We have, with $C=\sup_n\|f_n\|^2$,
\begin{align}
 k(m)&\leq \int_F s_m^{1/2}\,s_m^{1/2}\leq\int_F f\,s_m^{1/2}=\lim_n\int_Ff_n\,s_m^{1/2}\\[0.3cm]
&\leq \sup_n\|f_n\|_2\,\bigg(\int_Fs_m\bigg)^{1/2}\\[0.3cm]
&\leq C\,(k(m)+1)^{1/2}\leq 2C\,k(m)^{1/2}.
\end{align}
This implies that $k(m)$ is bounded, a contradiction.